# Multiple definition of C++. How to split C++ program properly?

Tags: c++, class, header

I wrote a program that works without problems, but the thing I am afraid of is that I get a lot of warnings, when I compile it with -Wall option ( it's program written in C and C++). Actually there is only one type of warning, but occurs many times : Multiple definition of .... ( contructors , destructors, and functions ). I thought I did it correcly, but obviously I am wrong. I have 9 files:

```
Server.h     
Server.cpp - implements methods declared in Server.h

RankingCreator.h
RankingCreator.cpp - implements methods declared in RankingCreator.h

Parser.h
Parser.cpp - implements methods declared in Parser.h

PageHandler.h
PageHandler.cpp - implements methods declared in PageHandler.h
```

and

```
Main.cpp
```

- all header files are included in this file, because I use and combine
    functionality of all classes here

Each .cpp file except Main.cpp contains only one corresponding .h file included, for instance Server.cpp contains #include "server.h" and no more .h/.cpp files listed above ( but it does contain headers like stdio.h and string.h ). I can post whole warning message here and code of classes, but the lenght of error is about 50 lines, and all classes would be about 1000 lines, so tell me if it is really needed to solve this. Any idea how to solve this? Do I have to make every function inline or something? Every header file has #if def block at the beginning.

EDIT:
Here is the warning log :

g++ LearnTidyCurl.cpp MyParser.cpp PageHandler.cpp RankingCreator.cpp Server.cpp -lcurl -ltidy -o -Wall Wynik

Here is code of one of my header files, see the way of ifdefs :

```
#ifndef RANKINGCREATOR_H_
#define RANKINGCREATOR_H_


#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//using namespace std;

struct rankingElement {
    std::string url;
    int rank;
    bool operator() (rankingElement i, rankingElement j) { return (i.rank >     j.rank);}

}  ;

bool operator==(const rankingElement& elem, const std::string& url);

class RankingCreator {
public:
    rankingElement compareRankingElements;
    const static int MAX_QUERY_RESULT_SIZE = 20;
    RankingCreator();
    virtual ~RankingCreator();
    bool checkPageRank( rankingElement rElement,  std::vector<rankingElement> &ranking );
    void insertIntoRanking( rankingElement rElement,  std::vector<rankingElement>& ranking);

};

#endif /* RANKINGCREATOR_H_ */
```

I threw warning message out, because it makes this topic unreadable.
Btw. I use include guards auto-generated by Eclipse - shouldn't they be just fine? ( When creating a new class they are automatically created )

EDIT:

You can download gedit file with error log here :

http://www4.zippyshare.com/v/62324366/file.html

I didn't want to post 105-lined error here and in addition it is in crap format, so would not good look here.

Server.h :

```
#ifndef SERVER_H_
#define SERVER_H_

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector> 

...body...

#endif /* SERVER_H_ */
```

PageHandler.h

```
#ifndef PAGEHANDLER_H_
#define PAGEHANDLER_H_

#include <tidy.h>
#include <buffio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

... body ...

#endif /* PAGEHANDLER_H_ */
```

MyParser.h

```
#ifndef MYPARSER_H_
#define MYPARSER_H_

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>

...body...

#endif /* MYPARSER_H_ */
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include "MyParser.h"
#include "PageHandler.h"
#include "RankingCreator.h"
#include "Server.h"

#define NO_ERROR 0

std::string convertIntToString(int input) {

    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << input;
    std::string tmpStr = ss.str();

return tmpStr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

... body ...
return 0;
}
```

MyParser.cpp

```
#include "MyParser.h"
```

PageHandler.cpp

```
#include "PageHandler.h"
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"
```

RankingCreator.cpp

```
#include "RankingCreator.h"
```

Comment: How are you compiling your program? What does your `Makefile` look like?

Comment: The error is important. As to the code, don't post it all. Post code relevant to one of the lines reported by the error?

Comment: Please post some representative error messages, since this is really vague. In general, it is "good" to remove all warnings. The compiler can be your friend. Yes, your program seems to run well, but the kind of things the compiler warns you about are the kind of things that can generate subtle (hard to find) bugs in a larger program. So my advise is to learn to program for no errors.

Comment: Can you paste the ifndef block you used? I think that sounds like it's not working right.

Comment: What do your guard #ifdefs look like? Easiest explanation would be that they're not working as intended.

Comment: You mean each header has the #ifndef / #define / #endif block?

Comment: The error is the most important thing, you should remove not it from the question. In any case, those **are not warnings**. Those are linker errors. They happen because you have defined things in more than one place. Are you perchance #including a .cpp file instead of a header?

Comment: CashCow - yes exactly.
Martinho I checked it and my Main includes all .h files NOT .cpp files.

Comment: Please expand `...body...` for PageHandler  as it seems to have the most repetition and for Server.  At the moment it doesn't seem like you have the implementation actually in the cpp but rather in the h.

Answer (score 1):

Change your inclusion guards:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H

//Code

#endif
```

And I bet your problem goes away.  Obviously make sure each FILENAME_H is unique :)  And remember - each header needs this around all it's code, but it shouldn't be in your source files.

Comment: I have done it in exactly the same way you specified it. You can see example of one of header files above. Those are auto-generated inclusion guards by eclipse. Any idea what else can be wrong?

Comment: I need to see the real error message, and the #includes at the top of all your files.  The code you've provided isn't the problem, and there isn't enough information in the question to guess without seeing the other code or the real error message.

Comment: Ok I provided what you said could help, can you now please look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My work's firewall actually blocks the site you hosted the error message on - but chances are the first 4-5 lines are where your first error is - usually the rest of a huge error message is fallout.  Look for global functions/class definitions in different files with the same name (same for enumerations/constants/etc).  Make sure didn't miss a ; at the end of any class.  Don't have full function defs outside classes in a header file.  If you used any templates make sure they're all in the .h file and not the .cpp file unless they're template specializations.  I'll check in later if I can.

Comment: I've been checking this for ages and I lost hope :P
I really don't know what can be wrong, it seems to me that I am doing everything correctly, but still getting those errors.. If you have time and if you are willing to help I can send you text file with error log via e-mail.

Comment: I'll take a quick look, but not promising I can fix it :p johnwhumphreys at hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Write your header files the following way:

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
//...
#endif
```

They are called `#include guards` to avoid double inclusion problems. Read about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

If you are ever developing on MVSC++, you can use `#pragma once` as a first line of each header, but the first solution is portable on every platform.

Comment: Names starting with underscores in global scope are reserved.

Comment: Why do you need `#else` for an include guard? It's a really bad idea to change behavior depending on how many times a header has been included...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, just on a separate note, why is it bad? how would the behavior change when a header is included?